# Tell fileSystemWatcher to wait

Tags: c#, file-watcher

I have some files that are written to a folder.First there are 2 files written and after 10-20 minutes the next 2 files.

**My question is:**

Is there any possible way to tell the file system watcher 
to wait until all 4 files are in the folder before executing my code?

Comment: Create a class, and create an event that fires when all 4 entries are there

Comment: If you know the name of the last file that will be written, you can use the Filter property to wait only for events that pertain to this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @BugFinder 's suggestion I created something similar but didn't test. Hope it is useful:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CustomFileWatcher
{
    public class CustomFileWatcher : IDisposable
    {
        private FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher;
        private IList<string> fileList;
        private IList<string> createdFiles;

        public event EventHandler FilesCreated;
        protected void OnFilesCreated(EventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = FilesCreated;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, e);
        }

        public CustomFileWatcher(IList<string> waitForTheseFiles, string path)
        {
            fileList = waitForTheseFiles;
            createdFiles = new List<string>();
            fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path);
            fileWatcher.Created += fileWatcher_Created;
        }

        void fileWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var item in fileList)
            {
                if (fileList.Contains(e.Name))
                {
                    if (!createdFiles.Contains(e.Name))
                    {
                        createdFiles.Add(e.Name);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (createdFiles.SequenceEqual(fileList))
                OnFilesCreated(new EventArgs());
        }

        public CustomFileWatcher(IList<string> waitForTheseFiles, string path, string filter)
        {
            fileList = waitForTheseFiles;
            createdFiles = new List<string>();
            fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path, filter);
            fileWatcher.Created += fileWatcher_Created;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (fileWatcher != null)
                fileWatcher.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IList<string> waitForAllTheseFilesToBeCopied = new List<string>();
            waitForAllTheseFilesToBeCopied.Add("File1.txt");
            waitForAllTheseFilesToBeCopied.Add("File2.txt");
            waitForAllTheseFilesToBeCopied.Add("File3.txt");

            string watchPath = @"C:\OutputFolder\";

            CustomFileWatcher customWatcher = new CustomFileWatcher(waitForAllTheseFilesToBeCopied, watchPath);

            customWatcher.FilesCreated += customWatcher_FilesCreated;
        }

        static void customWatcher_FilesCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // All files created.
        }
    }
```